# How to pass direct string as parameter in objc_msgSend()?

Tags: iphone

I am trying to make a simple example using c in ios.And I have written following code to present a view.It is working fine.But the problem is that I want to pass direct text to set in to the UILabel of which I have created object.

```
BOOL AppDel_didFinishLaunching(struct AppDel *self, SEL _cmd, void *application, void *options)
{
    self->window = objc_msgSend(objc_getClass("UIWindow"), sel_getUid("alloc"));
    self->window = objc_msgSend(self->window, sel_getUid("initWithFrame:"), (struct CGRect) { 0, 0, 320, 480 });

    id viewController = objc_msgSend(objc_msgSend(objc_getClass("UIViewController"), sel_getUid("alloc")), sel_getUid("init"));

    id view = objc_msgSend(objc_msgSend(objc_getClass("View"), sel_getUid("alloc")), sel_getUid("initWithFrame:"), (struct CGRect) { 0, 0, 320, 480 });

    id label=objc_msgSend(objc_msgSend(objc_getClass("UILabel"), sel_getUid("alloc")), sel_getUid("initWithFrame:"),(struct CGRect){20,20,200,30});
    objc_msgSend(label, sel_getUid("setBackgroundColor:"),objc_msgSend(objc_getClass("UIColor"), sel_getUid("greenColor")));

    objc_msgSend(label, sel_getUid("setText:"),?); //here how to set text by direct string?

    objc_msgSend(view, sel_getUid("addSubview:"),label);
    objc_msgSend(objc_msgSend(viewController, sel_getUid("view")), sel_getUid("addSubview:"), view);
    objc_msgSend(self->window, sel_getUid("setRootViewController:"), viewController);
    objc_msgSend(self->window, sel_getUid("makeKeyAndVisible"));

    return YES;
}
```

**objc_msgSend(label, sel_getUid("setText:"),?); //In this line i have to pass string.**

have u any idea?
Thanks!.

Comment: objc_msgSend(label, sel_getUid("setText:"),@"yourstring");

Comment: showing error Expected Expression

Comment: `NSString *str = @"yourstring"; objc_msgSend(label, sel_getUid("setText:"),str);`

Comment: NSString *string = @"yourString";
    objc_msgSend(label, sel_getUid("setText:"),string);

Comment: NSString not detecting

Comment: @Sudha I have written the same.but was wondering why direct constant string was not working..

Comment: because it is not objective c

Comment: @Hercules what's the extension of this file? and if it's a c file then try `objc_msgSend(label, sel_getUid("setText:"),"My String");`

Comment: @InderKumarRathore sorry, I didn't see that u have written same

Comment: @Sudha you can see it above your comment:)

Comment: @InderKumarRathore I didn't refresh my page yr thats why

Comment: @Sudha it's all right :) `@Hercules` have you tried normal c string?

Comment: "My String" also not working because c has not string

Comment: @Hercules can you tell me the extension of the file `.c` , `.cpp`, `.m` or `.mm` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
objc_msgSend(label, sel_getUid("setText:"),CFSTR("This is my string."));
```